# 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, dataframe, series

I have a groupedBy Series and am trying to perform a shift on each group. But the required shift per group is not always the same, hence I created a lookup dict from which I want to extract the shift of each respective item.

My Code:

```
shifted = shifted.groupby(by=["itemID", "date"]).shift(lookUp[shifted["itemID"]][expectedLagName])
```

This does not work since shifted["itemID"] returns a dataframe this is mutable, but since its groupedBy there should be only a single value and I do not know how to get that. Any ideas?

Reproducing Code:

```
data=range(1,101)
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.columns=["a"]
df["b"]= round(df["a"]/5)
lookUp={}
for i in range(1,21):
    lookUp[i] = round(i/2)

df = df.groupby(by=["b"]).shift(lookUp[df["b"]])
print(df)
```

Comment: that would be the row number right? I dont think I can make a matching lookup dict

Comment: sorry, I thought It would return a unique integer. my bad

Comment: The itemID is a unique integer, but I cannot access the value with that method. All I get returned is a dataframe containing that single integer

Answer (score 0):

There is a different Method to access the key name:
e.g.

```
result=df.groupby(by=["b"]).apply(lambda x:x.shift(lookUp[x.name]))
result=result.drop(["b"],axis=1)
result.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

This creates shifts on group levels, while performing a lookup to get the desired lag value. Only issue for me is, that the function is also applied to the group key, hence the drop call.